# greasemonkey code modification

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A user has helped me find hidden values in a page and display it using alert. If there are radio buttons and one of them is related to this value,is there a way to select the radio button automatically rathar than displaying the value in alert box.. Thanks...

the code is as follows:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute("name") == "ans") {
    alert(inputs[i].getAttribute("value"));
  }
}
```

this "value" must be selected in the radio button rather than alerting...

the html code is here:

Thus i need the option with value "Underlying Unity of Human Behaviour" to be checked after the page loads.. Thanks

`<table style="margin-left:20px"  align="center"  width="450" border=0>

                        <form name="bloogs" action="/mywebsite.php" id="bloogs" method="post" >

                    <tr><td align="left" class="formHeading"  colspan=2 ><b><font size="4px"> world</font></b></td>
    <td class="log" align="right" width=150  ><a href="website.php">Back to <br>Regular Index</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3 align="right" valign="top" height="30px"><div id="Time" style=""></td>
</tr>

                           <input type="hidden" name="ans" value="Underlying Unity of Human Behaviours" />
                         <input type="hidden" name="pno" value="3" />
                           <input type="hidden" name="quesid" value="3005" />
                                <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width=20><b>3.&nbsp;</b>
                                </td>
                                    <td class="ques" colspan=2>Which is the basic assumption of case study?</td>
                                </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td height="10" class="Textbold" colspan=2></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td></td>
                                    <td  class="" colspan=2><div class="ans" id="opt1" style="" ><input  type="radio" id="r1" name="opt" value="Data"> Data</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td></td>

                                    <td class="" colspan=2><div class="ans" id="opt2" style="" ><input  type="radio" id="r2" name="opt" value="Necessity"> Necessity</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td></td>
                                    <td class="" colspan=2><div class="ans" id="opt3" style="" ><input   type="radio" id="r3" name="opt" value="Observation"> Observation</div></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td></td>
                                    <td class="" colspan=2><div class="ans" id="opt4" style="" ><input type="radio" id="r4" name="opt" value="Underlying Unity of Human Behaviours"> Underlying Unity of Human Behaviours</div></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr><td></td>
                                  <td height="20"> </td> </td>

                                </tr>
                                                            <tr height=50><td align='right' width=350 colspan=3><input class='button' id='checkans' value='Attempt'  type='submit' name='checkans'/>
                <input class='button' id='' value='Skip'  type='submit' name='skip'/></td></tr></form>     </td>
</tr>

</table>`

Comment: How do you know that a radio button is related to a hidden field? Currently, `inputs` contains any `<input>` HTML element. Can you provide some sample HTML and explain better what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to check the radio button?

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

```
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute("name") == "ans") {
    inputs[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

[see here](http://javascriptkit.com/javatutors/radiocheck.shtml) :D

Comment: na, this code dint work.. and the sample code is
 
<form id="bloog" method="post" action= "/newpage.php" name="bloog">

The hidden content is present as:

<input type="hidden" value="abcd" name="ans">

now there are different radio buttons with different values.. one of these choices is abcd and i need that radio button to be checked after the page loads...
Thanks